# Oracle Profile definition CONNECT_TIME

Tags: oracle

The definition of **CONNECT_TIME** for profile , As per oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm)

> CONNECT_TIME 
>   Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session,
>   expressed in minutes.

I guess what they mean by connect time is the time execution of the procedure overall.

Is there a way to limit the connect time for the execution of the query in the procedure? For example, if procedure has 3 execution queries , and any query exceeds the specified time limit, then the session should be aborted or killed.

Comment: You need to limit that by elapsed time, not CPU time (per call)? I think you're looking for [resource manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/cncptdba.htm#CNCPT860) rather than profiles? Speficially the [execution time limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#ADMIN11857). Also, limiting the connect time implies dedicated sessions, so wouldn't play well with connection pools, for example.

Comment: @AlexPoole I will stick with profile for now however I have a question , can I make connect_time in seconds ?

Comment: No, only in minutes - you can't limit the session to 15 seconds, say, if that's what you're trying to do. That's not really what it's for, and the resource manager is there for fine-grained control. There is a way to kill a query (well, its session) [after a certain time](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8966741067544#25577950373941) but it seems a bit brutal.

Comment: @AlexPoole so you are saying with resource manager I can assign the execution time in seconds ?

Comment: Well yes, but CPU seconds, [and it's an optimiser estimate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#r19c1-t49); so the profile CPU limits might be just as good for you I suppose.

Comment: thanks for your valuable information, I will try both and see which suit for me , however I have a dump question related to profile , I have created a profile 
create profile APP_USER limit
  connect_time 1;
alter user scripts profile APP_USER; then I have run a procedure ,however it took about 153,732 seconds to finish , shouldnt be about 60 seconds ? is there something wrong ? @AlexPoole

Comment: You logged in as `scripts` after changing its profile? I haven't played around with this aspect enough... do you maybe get an error if you try to do anything new *after* the connect time expires? "If a user exceeds the CONNECT_TIME ... the database ... ends the session. When the user process next issues a call, the database returns an error." Where "next" will be after your  procedure completes, I think. So CPU limits might be needed.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes logged as scripts , I am able to execute queries normaly. should I add something or what ?

Comment: You may not have resource limits enabled. The Oracle documentation that you referred to says "Enable resource limits dynamically with the ALTER SYSTEM statement or with the initialization parameter RESOURCE_LIMIT. This parameter does not apply to password resources. Password resources are always enabled." I checked a couple of our databases and resource_limit was false.

Answer (score 0):

> **I guess what they mean by connect time is the time execution of the procedure overall.**

No, it is the maximum lifetime of the session, whether it is executing anything or not.

> **Is there a way to limit the ... execution of the query in the procedure?**

No, for two reasons.

First, all the profile limits are by call not by statement with in a call.  In your example, the three statements would all use the same limits.  Their total combined usage (of CPU or whatever) would not be able to exceed the limit.

Second, none of the profile options let you specify time per call.  You can specify I/O per call and CPU per call -- usually that's what people care about.  If a query is not consuming any CPU or I/O resources -- for example, if it is blocked waiting for a lock to clear -- what do you care how long it takes?